# Find files in a directory copy to a new file name

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed

Want to copy the files which has 63 in its name , change it to 64 and copy it in the same directory.  How can i do it.

Tried using awk,sed not working.

```
ls *63*
```

For example if the file is `test63.txt` it should get copied to `test64.txt` in the same directory . if the file is `63test.txt` it should get copied to `64text.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
for f in *63*; do newname=`echo $f | sed 's/63/64/'`; cp $f $newname; done
```

Broken down into multiple lines:

```
for f in *63*; do
  newname=`echo $f | sed 's/63/64/'`
  cp $f $newname
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Tried the below way using awk . ls \*61\*  | awk '{varr=$1; gsub("61","99",$varr); print $1;}' .   gsub replaces $1  variable even i perform the gsub on varr.  How can i make gsub not to replace the . $1 variable

Comment: Shell programming is an arcane art, unfortunately: (a) double-quote your variable references (b) `$(…)` is preferable to `\`…\``, (c) avoid calling external utilities in a shell loop when parameter expansions will do.

Comment: @Arav: There is no need for external utilities such as `awk` or even `ls`. That said: `gsub` is for replacing _all_ occurrences of a string; use `sub` instead. Prefix `$` is only used to refer to _fields_ in `awk`, not variables, so you'd have to use `varr`, not `$varr`. If the value of `varr` is a non-number, `$varr` is effectively interpreted as `$0` i.e., the entire input line.

Answer (score 1):

A generalized `bash` solution with a specifiable number that is incremented by 1:

```
n=63
for f in *"$n"*; do
  cp "$f" "${f/$n/$((n+1))}"
done
```